# How to set the default author email for every git commit in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In vscode 1.15.0 all my git commits use the wrong author email **@localhost** while the correct committer email address is used (git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81) on macOS 10.12.6). My configuration is as follows:

1. I clone & push the via ssh keys (from and to github)
2. Global user.name = Michael Jordan
3. Global user.email = michael.jordan@jordan.com
4. I even set user.email locally in my cloned repository as well
5. My Mac user is **mj** (so my home dir is */Users/mj*)

After committing my changes via vscode I execute `git log --format=full` with the following result:

```
commit <my git commit hash here>
Author: Michael Jordan <mj@localhost>
Commit: Michael Jordan <michael.jordan@jordan.com>

    This is my dummy commit message
```

This is weird, because in this scenario I'm both the author and committer. However, while the committer name/email is just fine it seems that the author name is correct and the **email is wrong**. For some reason the author email seems to my Mac user "mj" on localhost. On the other side the author name "Michael Jordan" seems to be fetched from the user.name settings of git.

I know I can fix this easily with

```
git commit --amend --author "Michael Jordan <michael.jordan@jordan.com>"
```

However, it's not really comfortable doing this after every commit via vscode.

How can I fix this once for all commits done via vscode - and for all repositories? It's worth to mention that I don't have such issues if I use Eclipse/egit (I guess it uses the settings from user.name and user.email).

I know that

```
git commit -m "My commit message" .
```

also uses "Michael Jordan " as the author (same as vscode). What I'm desperately looking for is a config option in vscode. And I want to avoid hooks...

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried the same thing on Win 8.1 with the latest git version 2.14.1 and the latest x64 vscode 1.15.0 - and it works just fine there! Here the author is just as expected (So both COmmiter and Author are the same):

`Michael Jordan <michael.jordan@jordan.com>`

After that I installed the git version 2.14.1 on my Mac and tried it there. Here it did not work - the author email is wrong. In both cases I cloned the git repo from GitHub - so I really had the clean repo both on Win and Mac. The only difference must be that on the Mac I have configured ssh keys for GitHub, which I don't have on my Win 8.1 machine.

Comment: I think you're going to have to rewrite the entire history to do this.  This question has been asked before, search around and you will find the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I know how to do this, but I want to avoid doing this for each of my repos and taking care everytime I commit something.

Comment: You should _always_ take care when you commit…

Comment: You are correct. It's not like I don't take care. All I want is to have the commit setting in vscode to allow me setting the author. And in fact, why is user.name used while user.email is not used for author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what I found in my .bash_profile:

```
...
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Michael Jordan"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="mj@localhost"
...
```

This is overwriting user.name and user.email

My fault :-(